# keeps saying Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This code keeps saying segmentation fault.

```
for(i=0; i<(numTopps-1); i++)
    {
            if(kcalTopp[i]<kcalTopp[i+1])
            {
                temp=*kcalTopp[i];
                *kcalTopp[i]=*kcalTopp[i+1];
                *kcalTopp[i+1]=temp;
            }
    }
```

I think above part is a problem.
but I can't figure what is the problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sort(int *kcalTopp[], int numTopps);

int main(void)
{  
int numTopps, doughPrice, eachToppPrice, kcalDough, i, j, totalKcal, highest, kcalperDol;
scanf("%d %d %d %d", &numTopps, &doughPrice, &eachToppPrice, &kcalDough);

int *kcalTopp;
kcalTopp=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*numTopps);

    for(i=0; i<numTopps; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &kcalTopp[i]);
    }

    totalKcal=kcalDough;
    highest=totalKcal/doughPrice;

    sort(&kcalTopp, numTopps);

    for(i=0; i<numTopps; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=i; j++)
        {
            totalKcal=totalKcal+kcalTopp[j];
            kcalperDol=totalKcal/(doughPrice+i*eachToppPrice);
            if(kcalperDol>highest)
            {
                highest=kcalperDol;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d", highest);

    return 0;
}

void sort(int *kcalTopp[], int numTopps)
{

int temp, i;

    for(i=0; i<(numTopps-1); i++)
    {
            if(kcalTopp[i]<kcalTopp[i+1])
            {
                temp=*kcalTopp[i];
                *kcalTopp[i]=*kcalTopp[i+1];
                *kcalTopp[i+1]=temp;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit your post to provide the input values you entered before seeing the seg-fault.  I have not seen a seg-fault.

Comment: When the very first line of the program is `scanf`, the first refactoring is to replace that call and parse `argv` instead.

Comment: Dare I ask why you're only partly using (questionable) additional levels of indirection ? That should be your first clue. The formal parameters to `sort` should be `int kcalTopp[], int nnumTopps`, and the calling code in `main` should simply pass in `kcalTopp, numTopps` ; the `&` literally looks like a guess at solving a compiler warning. Further, all `*kcalTopp[n]` should lose the `*` in `sort`.

Comment: You don't check any of the values returned by scanf.  Did it successfully read any data?  Is numTopps a positiive value?  Did `malloc` fail?

Comment: `(*kcalTopp)[i]` != `*kcalTopp[i]`

Comment: @WilliamPursell It's completely wrong, as I stated. He's not passing an array of pointers; he's passing an address of a single pointer. The `sort` function is using incorrect indirection. It almost looks like it was written first, then the calling code was patched up with a `&` on the first argument to squelch the ensuing compiler warning. That `sort` doesn't actually *sort* is also a problem, but more an afterthought at this point.

Comment: @WhozCraig You are probably right.  It is idiomatically a disaster, but it's entirely possible to simply do `if( (*kcalTopp)[i] < (*kcalTopp)[i+1) ...`.  I would agree that such a fix would be a terrible thing to do, and could be characterized as "completely wrong".

Comment: It's not characterized completely wrong, it's UB. Doing what he's doing with what is expected to be an array of pointers, whilst feeding it the address of exactly *one* pointer (`&kcalTopp` in `main`) is a disaster, and a guaranteed for UB as soon as any index > 0 is used (which is guaranteed because of the `i+1` ideology of the OP's (apparently) incomplete bubblesort. `int *kcalTopp[]` is broken from inception. The comparison is broken, the indexing is broken; you literally can't get *more* broken. thus "completely wrong" And I just realized you thought I mean *your* code. Sry.

Comment: @WhozCraig.  No, he is not passing an array of pointers.  The declaration `void sort(int *kcalTopp[], int numTopps);` is identical to the declaration `void sort(int **kcalTopp, int numTopps);`, and he is passing a pointer to a pointer to int.  The underlying array can easily be accessed, and although the current code invokes UB by incorrectly indexing, that can be fixed by simply writing `(*kcalTopp)` everywhere as needed.  Such a fix would be completely wrong (idiomatically) but it would work

Comment: @WilliamPursell thus my comment, "I just realized you thought I was talking about your code" (i.e. your adjustment). I wasn't; I was talking about the OP's post.Sry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, your problem is the sort function you described, as you suspected. Are you aware what `*kcalTopp[i]=*kcalTopp[i+1];` does exactly? You get as parameter an `int *array[]` which is equivalent to `int **array` (you can see it as an array of arrays of ints). So when you tell C to access `array[i]` you will access the i-th array. This is a pointer, and in fact `*kcalTopp[i]` will be the first element from the i-th array. What you are doing here is swapping first elements from the arrays, but in practice you have a single array of ints (or more technically, an array of length 1 of arrays). The simplest fix is to write:

```c
temp=(*kcalTopp)[i];
(*kcalTopp)[i]=(*kcalTopp)[i+1];
(*kcalTopp)[i+1]=temp;
```

just to change the precedence of the operators. Now, what we achieved is: we take the first array from the array list (it's the only one we have, isn't it?) with `(*kcalTopp)`; this is an `int *`, not `int **` anymore. Now you can safely access the i-th element from it.

Without parentheses, you would first access the i-th array, because in `*kcalTopp[i]`, the `[i]` part will execute before the `*` part.

Anyway, to simplify things, you are not required to take as parameter an `int *kcalTopp[]`, you can simply take `int kcalTop[]` or `int *kcalTopp` and not use `*` anymore:

```c
temp = kcalTopp[i];
kcalTopp[i] = kcalTopp[i+1];
kcalTopp[i+1] = temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

The original code in your post is using an extra (unnecessary) layer of indirection for `kcalTopp`, resulting in attempts to manipulate an array of addresses (pointers) as opposed to manipulating `int` values pointed to in memory.  This in turn is likely to be the reason you are seeing segmentation faults, which occur when attempting to access memory that you do not own. For some input values, and depending on what day you run your program, it may run, and it may crash.
(This is sometimes referred to as [undefined behavior](https://riptutorial.com/c/topic/364/undefined-behavior), and is the reason that the problem will not always manifest itself, making you think your program is flawless, when it is not.)

The following contains edits to your original code *for the purpose of illustrating some of the suggestions in comments*. (not to fix every logic error.)  The edits do include treating `kcalTopp` as a pointer to `int` memory as opposed to an array of `int *`.  See in-line comments for clarifications:

```
//void sort(int *kcalTopp[], int numTopps);//*kcalTopp[] is an array of pointers 
void sort(int *kcalTopp, int numTopps);//*kcalTopp is a pointer to 'int' memory

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    int numTopps, doughPrice, eachToppPrice, kcalDough, i, j, totalKcal, highest, kcalperDol;
    //scanf("%d %d %d %d", &numTopps, &doughPrice, &eachToppPrice, &kcalDough);

    if(argv != 5) //simple reading in of command line args
    {
        printf("4 input values required.  Exiting");
        return 0;
    }

    //note, each of these calls includes simple for test for success before going on 
    numTopps = strtol(argv[1], (char **) NULL, 10);
    if(errno == ERANGE) {printf("argv[1] Bad input, exiting"); return 0;}
    doughPrice = strtol(argv[2], (char **) NULL, 10);
    if(errno == ERANGE) {printf("argv[2] Bad input, exiting"); return 0;}
    eachToppPrice = strtol(argv[3], (char **) NULL, 10);
    if(errno == ERANGE) {printf("argv[3] Bad input, exiting"); return 0;}
    kcalDough = strtol(argv[4], (char **) NULL, 10);
    if(errno == ERANGE) {printf("argv[4] Bad input, exiting"); return 0;}

    int *kcalTopp;
    //This statement (without cast) is sufficient to create memory for kcalTopp
    kcalTopp = malloc(sizeof(int)*numTopps);
    if(!kcalTopp)//should always test before using memory
    {
         printf("memory allocation failed, exiting");
         return 0;
    }

    for(i=0; i<numTopps; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &kcalTopp[i]);
    }

    totalKcal=kcalDough;
    highest=totalKcal/doughPrice;

    //sort(&kcalTopp, numTopps);
    //     ^ not needed
    sort(kcalTopp, numTopps);

    for(i=0; i<numTopps; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=i; j++)
        {
            totalKcal=totalKcal+kcalTopp[j];
            kcalperDol=totalKcal/(doughPrice+i*eachToppPrice);
            if(kcalperDol>highest)
            {
                highest=kcalperDol;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d", highest);

    return 0;
}

void sort(int *kcalTopp, int numTopps)//note removal of []
{

    int temp, i;

    for(i=0; i<(numTopps-1); i++)
    {
            if(kcalTopp[i]<kcalTopp[i+1])
            {
                temp=kcalTopp[i];//note removal of '*' from all kcalTopp
                kcalTopp[i]=kcalTopp[i+1];
                kcalTopp[i+1]=temp;
            }
    }
}
```